# Regular Expression: Replace except from specific characters and whitespace

Tags: java, regex

I am coding in Java and I have a string where I want to keep letters, digits, ":",  "-" and whitespaces and remove everything else. So, I have used this piece of code:

```
str=str.replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z#:-\\s*]", "");
```

It doesn't work.

It does work fine until

```
str=str.replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z#:-]", "");
```

where everything else, except from letters, digits and the characters ":" and "-" is removed

But when I am trying to add the condition for whitespace characters I am facing problems.

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about `#` and `*`? They are in your character class, but you didn't mention them in your explanation of what your regex is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` when used within character class depicts range..

In your case you were actually trying to match characters from range `:` to `\s` which is an invalid range..

---

Move `-` to the start

```
[^-\\dA-Za-z#:\\s]
```

or end

```
[^\\dA-Za-z#:\\s-]
```

Comment: You should remove your last option. That is doing no good out there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.. Now i have [^\\A-Za-z\\s-] that returns an error  Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 3. Do you know why is that?

Comment: @user2008973 it should be  `[^\\dA-Za-z\\s-]` ! `\\A` is not a valid escape sequence in regex

Answer (score 1):

The dash must be the first or last character in a character class, or it will be interpreted as a range indicator (as in `[A-Z]`); in your case `[:-\\s]` is a meaningless range. Use

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z#:\\s-]+", "");
```

(or did you want to keep asterisks in your text, too)?